# Returning a specific XML child with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have some XML to work with, something like this:

```
<admin_list>
    <admin>
      <name>user1</name>
      <authentication_source>Local</authentication_source>
    </admin>
    <admin>
      <name>user2</name>
      <authentication_source>Local</authentication_source>
    </admin>
  </admin_list>
```

I can't seem to retrieve a specific admin though. The following:

```
  $admin = "user1";
  foreach ($subxml as $child) {
                 if ($child->admin->name == $admin) {
                  var_dump($child);
                  }
             }
```

returns an array including both user1 and user2. How can I go about outputting the XML of only the selected user. (in this case user1) So my desired output is:

```
 <admin>
      <name>user1</name>
      <authentication_source>Local</authentication_source>
 </admin>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using XPATH would probably be a good idea

```
$query = $simple_xml_resource->xpath('/admin_list/admin[name = "' . $name . '"]');

if(count($query) == 0)
{
    //no users found
}
else
{
    $user = $query[0];
    echo $user->asXML(); //outputs the XML
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Does [name require a closing bracket?

Comment: Yes, that would be it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you think of any other reason why the query would be returning null when the name does exist? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Found the problem. It was the preceding "/" on ->xpath('/admin_list
without the / it worked great. Thanks!